# Simple hello world example for Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I am looking for the simplest possible example of an hello-world experience with Apache flink.

Assume I have just installed flink on a clean box, what is the bare minimum I would need to do to 'make it do something'. I realize this is quite vague, here are some examples.

Three python examples from the terminal:

```
python -c "print('hello world')"
python hello_world.py
python python -c "print(1+1)"
```

Of course a streaming application is a bit more complicated, but here is something similar that I did for spark streaming earlier:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#a-quick-example

As you see these examples have some nice properties:

1. They are minimal
2. There are minimal dependencies on other tools/resources
3. The logic can be trivially adjusted (e.g different number or different separator)

So my question:

## What is the simplest hello world example for Flink

---

What I found so far are examples with 50 lines of code that you need to compile.

If this cannot be avoided due to point 3, then something that satisfies points 1 and 2 and uses (only) jars that are shipped by default, or easily available from a reputable source, would also be fine.

Comment: Why the downvote, is it unclear? -- A hello world example is surely relevant enough?! Rephrased the title in case that was the problem.

Comment: What's wrong with classic word count ?

Comment: @MIkCode is probably right, the classic word count connected with reading a file or creating the DataStream from Seq should be the easiest.

Comment: @MIkCode Not sure what the classic is, but the last two things I found were 50-125 lines of code which need to be compiled. I understand this may be needed for proper understanding, but I'm looking for a way around it. For instance with standard materials?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In most of Big data and related framework we give Word Count program as Hello World example.** Below is the code for word count in Flink:

```
final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    DataSet<String> text = env.fromCollection(Arrays.asList("This is line one. This is my line number 2. Third line is here".split(". ")));

    DataSet<Tuple2<String, Integer>> wordCounts = text
        .flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>>() {
          @Override
          public void flatMap(String line, Collector<Tuple2<String, Integer>> out) throws Exception {
            for (String word : line.split(" ")) {
              out.collect(new Tuple2<>(word, 1));
            }
          }
        })
        .groupBy(0)
        .sum(1);

wordCounts.print();
```

**Reading from a file**

```
final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env.setParallelism(1);

    //The path of the file, as a URI
    //(e.g., "file:///some/local/file" or "hdfs://host:port/file/path").
    DataSet<String> text = env.readTextFile("/path/to/file");

    DataSet<Tuple2<String, Integer>> wordCounts = text
        .flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>>() {
          @Override
          public void flatMap(String line, Collector<Tuple2<String, Integer>> out) throws Exception {
            for (String word : line.split(" ")) {
              out.collect(new Tuple2<String, Integer>(word, 1));
            }
          }
        })
        .groupBy(0)
        .sum(1);

    wordCounts.print();
```

Do not handle exception thrown on wordCounts.print() using try catch but instead add throw to method signature.

Add the following dependency to the pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Read about flatMap, groupBy, sum and other flink operations here : https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/

Flink Streaming documentation and examples: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/dev/datastream_api.html

Comment: Nice and short, however for streaming I would ideally get the string from the outside world somehow (terminal, file). Would it be easy to get the string from 'outside'? So people could see the processing in real-time.

Comment: To get the above working I had to make three additional changes (1)Add `org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator.configure();` as first line of the above program (2)For #1, add `<dependency>groupId>log4j</groupId><artifactId>log4j</artifactId><version>1.2.17</version></dependency>`, and finally add another dependency (3)`<dependency><groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId><artifactId>flink-clients_2.12</artifactId><version>1.8.0</version></dependency>`

Answer (score 6):

Ok, how about this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

  env.fromElements(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    .map(i -> 2 * i)
    .print();

  env.execute();
}
```

Comment: Will give others a chance to answer before I accept (and will check it out) but already up voted as this is much more in the spirit of things than anything I could find so far :-)

Comment: how do you submit that to flink?

Answer (score 1):

## Minimal steps with standard resources

I am not sure if this will be the ultimate answer, but have found that flink typically ships with examples, that allow for some easy interaction with minimal effort.

Here is a possible hello world example with standard resources that come with flink 1.9.1, based on the default wordcount:

1. Make sure your flink cluster is started, and that you have three terminals open in the flink directory.
2. In terminal 1 open a connection to the right port

`nc -l 9000`

3. In the same terminal on the next line type some text and hit enter

`Hello World`

4. In terminal 2 initiate the standard wordcount logic

`./bin/flink run examples/streaming/SocketWindowWordCount.jar --port 9000`

5. In terminal 3 check the result of the count

`tail -f log/flink-*-taskexecutor-*.out`

You should now see:

```
Hello : 1
World : 1
```

---

That's it, from here you can type more into terminal 1 and when you check the logs again you will see the updated wordcount.

If you already did this once before and want to start fresh, you could clear the logs (assuming a sandbox environment) with `rm  log/flink-*-taskexecutor-*.out`

Answer (score 0):

Using jbang with minimal libraries for Java:

```
///usr/bin/env jbang "$0" "$@" ; exit $?

//DEPS org.apache.flink:flink-java:1.18.1
//DEPS org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-java:1.18.1
//DEPS org.apache.flink:flink-clients:1.18.1

import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;

public class FlinkHelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        env.fromElements(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) // Source
                .map(i -> 2 * i) // Operator
                .print(); // Sink

        env.execute();
    }

}
```

Run with:

```
jbang FlinkHelloWorld.java
```