# Flink streaming example that generates its own data

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Earlier I asked about a simple [hello world example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59347209) for Flink. This gave me some good examples!

However I would like to ask for a more ‘streaming’ example where we generate an input value every second. This would ideally be random, but even just the same value each time would be fine.

The objective is to get a stream that ‘moves’ with no/minimal external touch.

Hence my question:

## How to show Flink actually streaming data without external dependencies?

I found how to show this with generating data externally and writing to Kafka, or listening to a public source, however I am trying to solve it with minimal dependence (like starting with GenerateFlowFile in Nifi).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example. This was constructed as an example of how to make your sources and sinks pluggable. The idea being that in development you might use a random source and print the results, for tests you might use a hardwired list of input events and collect the results in a list, and in production you'd use the real sources and sinks.

Here's the job:

```java
/*
 * Example showing how to make sources and sinks pluggable in your application code so
 * you can inject special test sources and test sinks in your tests.
 */

public class TestableStreamingJob {
    private SourceFunction<Long> source;
    private SinkFunction<Long> sink;

    public TestableStreamingJob(SourceFunction<Long> source, SinkFunction<Long> sink) {
        this.source = source;
        this.sink = sink;
    }

    public void execute() throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        DataStream<Long> LongStream =
                env.addSource(source)
                        .returns(TypeInformation.of(Long.class));

        LongStream
                .map(new IncrementMapFunction())
                .addSink(sink);

        env.execute();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TestableStreamingJob job = new TestableStreamingJob(new RandomLongSource(), new PrintSinkFunction<>());
        job.execute();
    }

    // While it's tempting for something this simple, avoid using anonymous classes or lambdas
    // for any business logic you might want to unit test.
    public class IncrementMapFunction implements MapFunction<Long, Long> {

        @Override
        public Long map(Long record) throws Exception {
            return record + 1 ;
        }
    }

}
```

Here's the `RandomLongSource`:

```java
public class RandomLongSource extends RichParallelSourceFunction<Long> {

    private volatile boolean cancelled = false;
    private Random random;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        super.open(parameters);
        random = new Random();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(SourceContext<Long> ctx) throws Exception {
        while (!cancelled) {
            Long nextLong = random.nextLong();
            synchronized (ctx.getCheckpointLock()) {
                ctx.collect(nextLong);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        cancelled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like this must be pretty much what I asked for. One thing that I am trying to understand is what the pace is/how to set it. Would it makes sense to add a 'wait 1 second' in the while loop?

Comment: You certainly could add a Thread.sleep in the source's run loop. Whether you want to or not depends on your goals. Flink handles backpressure gracefully, so the source will not overrun the rest of the pipeline, even w/o a sleep. If you want to see how the pipeline will behave when running flat out, then don't have it sleep, but if you want throttle the pipeline, go right ahead.